# ansible replace multiples lines before and after regexp

Tags: regex, ansible, regexp-replace, ansible-awx

I'm using ansible tower to modify a file .baroc, using the variable that the user filed in for regexp.

For exampe this is the file to modify :

```
AUTOMATION;
groupe_affectation='Test'';
msg_exception='APPLI 1';
mc_long_msg='eKBX';
commentaire='Automatic';
END

AUTOMATION;
groupe_affectation='Test'';
msg_exception='APPLI 1';
mc_long_msg='eKB42';
commentaire='Automatic';
END

AUTOMATION;
mc_service='.\* - PRE-PRODUCTION';
application_infogerant='toto|test';
mc_long_msg='eKB12345';
mc_host='';
mc_object_class='';
mc_object='';
mc_parameter='';
msg='';
groupe_affectation='EXPLOITATION_APPLICATIONS-TOTO';
commentaire='DT123';
END

\########################################################################################################################################################################

# TOTO - Affectation CA

\########################################################################################################################################################################

# TOTO - CTRLM

AUTOMATION;
mc_long_msg='eKB007';
ctm_application='test.';
ctm_group='';
ctm_jobname='';
ctm_datacenter='';
ctm_nodeid='';
ctm_msg='';
groupe_affectation='MCO_test';
commentaire='DT01';
END
AUTOMATION;
groupe_affectation='SUPPORT';
msg_exception='APPLI 4';
mc_long_msg='eKB007';
commentaire='Automatic';
END
```

On this one, I'd like to delete the entier bloc :

```
AUTOMATION;
groupe_affectation='Test'';
msg_exception='APPLI 1';
mc_long_msg='eKB42';
commentaire='Automatic';
END
```

Here is my Playbook :

```
---

- name: Suppression d'un eKB au fichier Paperboy
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Vérifier si le eKB est bien présent ########Check if the eKB is present
    lineinfile:
    path: /exemple/of/a/PATH.baroc
    line: "eKB042"
    state: absent
    check_mode: yes
    register: presence

  - name: Arrêter le playbook si le eKB n'est pas présent ########Stop the playbook if the eKB is absent
    fail:
    msg: "L'eKB042 n'est pas présent dans le fichier baroc."
    when: presence.changed

  - name: Copie du fichier baroc dans le old #Backup
    ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: /exemple/of/a/PATH.baroc
    dest: /exemple/of/an/old/PATH.baroc.soway.{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601_basic }}

  - name: Suppression de la règle au fichier PAPERBOY.baroc ########Delete bloc
    ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /exemple/of/a/PATH.baroc
    after: 'PAPERBOY(?:(?!PAPERBOY)(.|\\n))*eKB0031549'
    before: 'END(?!(.|\\n)eKB0031549)'
    regexp: '^.*(eKB042).$'
    replace: '! '
    ...
```

The problem is that it starts the last tastk without ending...
I know that everything before the last task works because I'm using it for an other purpose (adding lines to make new eKB) and it works fine. I think that the issue is with the regex I'm using... even if on regex101 it was ok.

So I'm open to the idea of either delete the bloc from AUTOMATION to END (best practice I think) or if too difficult, delete 3 lines before eKB and 2 lines after eKB ; since the playbook will always be used to delete similar blocs of automation. Longer blocs won't be deleted by this way and won't have the same eKB number

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Given the file

```ini
shell> cat PATH.baroc 
AUTOMATION;
groupe_affectation='Test'';
msg_exception='APPLI 1';
mc_long_msg='eKBX';
commentaire='Automatic';
END

PAPERBOY;
groupe_affectation='Test'';
msg_exception='APPLI 1';
mc_long_msg='eKB42';
commentaire='Automatic';
END

AUTOMATION;
mc_service='.\* - PRE-PRODUCTION';
application_infogerant='toto|test';
mc_long_msg='eKB12345';
mc_host='';
mc_object_class='';
mc_object='';
mc_parameter='';
msg='';
groupe_affectation='EXPLOITATION_APPLICATIONS-TOTO';
commentaire='DT123';
END

\########################################################################################################################################################################

# TOTO - Affectation CA

\########################################################################################################################################################################

# TOTO - CTRLM

AUTOMATION;
mc_long_msg='eKB007';
ctm_application='test.';
ctm_group='';
ctm_jobname='';
ctm_datacenter='';
ctm_nodeid='';
ctm_msg='';
groupe_affectation='MCO_test';
commentaire='DT01';
END
AUTOMATION;
groupe_affectation='SUPPORT';
msg_exception='APPLI 4';
mc_long_msg='eKB007';
commentaire='Automatic';
END
```

---

Q: Delete the entire bloc

```ini
PAPERBOY;
groupe_affectation='Test'';
msg_exception='APPLI 1';
mc_long_msg='eKB42';
commentaire='Automatic';
END
```

A: Read the file

```yaml
    - shell: cat PATH.baroc | egrep '.*;|END'
      register: out
```

and parse the content

```yaml
  test: "{{ out.stdout|
            split('END')|
            select|
            map('trim')|
            map('regex_replace', ';', '')|
            map('community.general.jc', 'ini') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  test:
  - AUTOMATION: ''
    commentaire: Automatic
    groupe_affectation: Test'
    mc_long_msg: eKBX
    msg_exception: APPLI 1
  - PAPERBOY: ''
    commentaire: Automatic
    groupe_affectation: Test'
    mc_long_msg: eKB42
    msg_exception: APPLI 1
  - AUTOMATION: ''
    application_infogerant: toto|test
    commentaire: DT123
    groupe_affectation: EXPLOITATION_APPLICATIONS-TOTO
    mc_host: ''
    mc_long_msg: eKB12345
    mc_object: ''
    mc_object_class: ''
    mc_parameter: ''
    mc_service: .\* - PRE-PRODUCTION
    msg: ''
  - AUTOMATION: ''
    commentaire: DT01
    ctm_application: test.
    ctm_datacenter: ''
    ctm_group: ''
    ctm_jobname: ''
    ctm_msg: ''
    ctm_nodeid: ''
    groupe_affectation: MCO_test
    mc_long_msg: eKB007
  - AUTOMATION: ''
    commentaire: Automatic
    groupe_affectation: SUPPORT
    mc_long_msg: eKB007
    msg_exception: APPLI 4
```

Modify what you want and write the block

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in test|reject('contains', 'PAPERBOY') %}
          {% for k,v in i.items() %}
          {% if loop.index == 1 %}
          {{ k }};
          {% else %}
          {{ k }}='{{ v }}';
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          END

          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
    AUTOMATION;
    groupe_affectation='Test'';
    msg_exception='APPLI 1';
    mc_long_msg='eKBX';
    commentaire='Automatic';
    END
  
    AUTOMATION;
    mc_service='.\* - PRE-PRODUCTION';
    application_infogerant='toto|test';
    mc_long_msg='eKB12345';
    mc_host='';
    mc_object_class='';
    mc_object='';
    mc_parameter='';
    msg='';
    groupe_affectation='EXPLOITATION_APPLICATIONS-TOTO';
    commentaire='DT123';
    END
  
    AUTOMATION;
    mc_long_msg='eKB007';
    ctm_application='test.';
    ctm_group='';
    ctm_jobname='';
    ctm_datacenter='';
    ctm_nodeid='';
    ctm_msg='';
    groupe_affectation='MCO_test';
    commentaire='DT01';
    END
  
    AUTOMATION;
    groupe_affectation='SUPPORT';
    msg_exception='APPLI 4';
    mc_long_msg='eKB007';
    commentaire='Automatic';
    END
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    test: "{{ out.stdout|
              split('END')|
              select|
              map('trim')|
              map('regex_replace', ';', '')|
              map('community.general.jc', 'ini') }}"

  tasks:

    - shell: cat PATH.baroc | egrep '.*;|END'
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: test

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in test|reject('contains', 'PAPERBOY') %}
          {% for k,v in i.items() %}
          {% if loop.index == 1 %}
          {{ k }};
          {% else %}
          {{ k }}='{{ v }}';
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          END

          {% endfor %}

    - copy:
        dest: test.ini
        content: |
          {% for i in test|reject('contains', 'PAPERBOY') %}
          {% for k,v in i.items() %}
          {% if loop.index == 1 %}
          {{ k }};
          {% else %}
          {{ k }}='{{ v }}';
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          END

          {% endfor %}
```

---

Q: Delete the entire bloc

```ini
AUTOMATION;
groupe_affectation='Test'';
msg_exception='APPLI 1';
mc_long_msg='eKBX';
commentaire='Automatic';
END
```

A: Put the blocks you want to delete into a list

```yaml
    blocks_del:
      - |
        AUTOMATION;
        groupe_affectation='Test'';
        msg_exception='APPLI 1';
        mc_long_msg='eKBX';
        commentaire='Automatic';
        END
```

Convert the blocks to lines

```yaml
    lines_del: "{{ blocks_del|map('split')|map('join', ' ') }}"

    lines: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in test %}
      {% for k,v in i.items() %}
      {% if loop.index == 1 %}
      - {{ k }};
      {% else %}
        {{ k }}='{{ v }}';
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
        END
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
```

and write the difference between the lists

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in lines|difference(lines_del) %}
          {% for j in i|split('; ') %}
          {{ j }}{% if not loop.last %};{% endif +%}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    PAPERBOY;
    groupe_affectation='Test'';
    msg_exception='APPLI 1';
    mc_long_msg='eKB42';
    commentaire='Automatic';
    END
  
    AUTOMATION;
    mc_service='.\* - PRE-PRODUCTION';
    application_infogerant='toto|test';
    mc_long_msg='eKB12345';
    mc_host='';
    mc_object_class='';
    mc_object='';
    mc_parameter='';
    msg='';
    groupe_affectation='EXPLOITATION_APPLICATIONS-TOTO';
    commentaire='DT123';
    END
  
    AUTOMATION;
    mc_long_msg='eKB007';
    ctm_application='test.';
    ctm_group='';
    ctm_jobname='';
    ctm_datacenter='';
    ctm_nodeid='';
    ctm_msg='';
    groupe_affectation='MCO_test';
    commentaire='DT01';
    END
  
    AUTOMATION;
    groupe_affectation='SUPPORT';
    msg_exception='APPLI 4';
    mc_long_msg='eKB007';
    commentaire='Automatic';
    END
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    test: "{{ out.stdout|
              split('END')|
              select|
              map('trim')|
              map('regex_replace', ';', '')|
              map('community.general.jc', 'ini') }}"

    blocks_del:
      - |
        AUTOMATION;
        groupe_affectation='Test'';
        msg_exception='APPLI 1';
        mc_long_msg='eKBX';
        commentaire='Automatic';
        END

    lines_del: "{{ blocks_del|map('split')|map('join', ' ') }}"

    lines: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in test %}
      {% for k,v in i.items() %}
      {% if loop.index == 1 %}
      - {{ k }};
      {% else %}
        {{ k }}='{{ v }}';
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
        END
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - shell: cat PATH.baroc | egrep '.*;|END'
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: lines

    - debug:
        var: lines_del

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in lines|difference(lines_del) %}
          {% for j in i|split('; ') %}
          {{ j }}{% if not loop.last %};{% endif +%}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
```

---

You can simplify the code by creating a list of dictionaries you want to delete. For example,

```yaml
    blocks_del:
      - AUTOMATION: ''
        commentaire: Automatic
        groupe_affectation: Test'
        mc_long_msg: eKBX
        msg_exception: APPLI 1
      - PAPERBOY: ''
        commentaire: Automatic
        groupe_affectation: Test'
        mc_long_msg: eKB42
        msg_exception: APPLI 1
```

Then, you can directly iterate the difference

```yaml
  test|difference(blocks_del):
  - AUTOMATION: ''
    application_infogerant: toto|test
    commentaire: DT123
    groupe_affectation: EXPLOITATION_APPLICATIONS-TOTO
    mc_host: ''
    mc_long_msg: eKB12345
    mc_object: ''
    mc_object_class: ''
    mc_parameter: ''
    mc_service: .\* - PRE-PRODUCTION
    msg: ''
  - AUTOMATION: ''
    commentaire: DT01
    ctm_application: test.
    ctm_datacenter: ''
    ctm_group: ''
    ctm_jobname: ''
    ctm_msg: ''
    ctm_nodeid: ''
    groupe_affectation: MCO_test
    mc_long_msg: eKB007
  - AUTOMATION: ''
    commentaire: Automatic
    groupe_affectation: SUPPORT
    mc_long_msg: eKB007
    msg_exception: APPLI 4
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. So there is two things to precise :
- I have put the wrong entry to delete from the fil, PAPERBOY shouldn't be there, it should be as all the others Automation. I have replace the sentence but it should be always the same word in the begening and at the end of the file.
- The user that want to delete a bloc doesn't know the content of the file, he only knows the eKB number. So he should only put as variable eKBXXX

Moreover the file should be modified, the sections with " ####### XX " should be maintained